# Quando usar sistema de cache no PHP?

Tags: php, cache

Andei lendo um pouco sobre o uso do cache em PHP, suas vantagens e desvantagens. Surgiram algumas dúvidas e etc.

Se eu tiver um sistema que só mostra textos com atualização (re-edição) dos mesmos, muito pequena, é aconselhável usar CACHE? Se sim, qual deveria usar e como?

Comment: Acho que a pergunta vale para qualquer plataforma, não apenas para PHP.

Answer (score 5):

Cache é algo meio abstrato, existem várias otimizações que você pode fazer em um sistema que se encaixam bem nessa palavra, como:

- Cache de páginas estáticas
- Cache de consultas ao banco de dados
- Cache de respostas de serviços
- Cache de opcodes

Acho que em boa parte dos casos, tanta preocupação com otimização é desnecessária, embora algumas façam parte das boas práticas de programação.

Tudo depende da carga do seu sistema. Se você está tendo problemas de performance (muito uso de banda, processamento, memória, espaço em disco, etc.), comece a fazer otimizações no sistema partido das mais simples para as mais complicadas.

Existem algumas dicas genéricas e bem fáceis de se implementar como:

- Sempre fique atento para os dois maiores vilões da performance: acesso a rede e acesso a disco.
- Algumas técnicas como o armazenamento em cache de arquivos estáticos no navegador do cliente usando cabeçalhos podem aliviar seus problemas com excesso de uso de banda.
- Importar bibliotecas comuns de CDNs de terceiros também pode ajudar um pouco com banda (Exemplo: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide)
- Evitar o uso de `SELECT *` ou adotar tabelas ARCHIVE ou MEMORY num sistema baseado em MySQL pode agilizar consultas.

E por aí vai...

Comment: Eu acho que "meio" é humildade. Cache é algo, de fato, abstrato. Fora isso, +1. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Sim, deve usar.

Em PHP, para um uso simples, como um website que roda em uma única máquina, use o APC, de preferência passando por um objeto seu que gerencie a leitura e gravação, como por exemplo, o Componente Cache do ZF2.

Cada texto seu deve ser um `id` único que identificará o `cache` (ex: `texto_id_776482`. No momento em que você exibe pela primeira vez o texto `776482`,
verifica se ele já está em cache e, se sim, exibe-o a partir do que recuperou do APC ou, se não, exibe e grava no APC o que recebeu do banco de dados.